# Can we use load_and_authorize_resource in the application_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancancan, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I want to define abilities for all the controllers of the application, is it possible to put the load_and_authorize_resource or authorize_resource call in the application_controller itself and have it trickle down to each controller?

Answer (score 0):

You theorically could but It would also try to load a Application object and then crash because Application is a reserved word in Rails as it is already used (See your config, application.rb for exemple).